# Solving a Maze Problem without exceeding the Heap Memory

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, java-8, maze

Link to the problem on HackerEarth. - [The Maze](https://www.hackerearth.com/ru/problem/algorithm/q1-33/)

I have tried this problem and now facing an issue in passing all the test cases.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
class SumTarget {
    static boolean[][] hole=new boolean[10001][10001];
    static boolean[][] temp=new boolean[10001][10001];
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        int k,t,i,j,n,m,w,count,x1,y1,x2,y2;
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            t=sc.nextInt();
            for(k=0;k<t;k++){
            n=sc.nextInt();
            m=sc.nextInt();
            w=sc.nextInt();
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    hole[i][j]=false;
                    temp[i][j]=false;
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<w;i++)
            {
                x1=sc.nextInt();
                y1=sc.nextInt();
                x2=sc.nextInt();
                y2=sc.nextInt();
                for(j=x1;j<=x2;j++)
                    hole[y1][j]=true;
            }
            pathtoexit(n-1,m-1);
            count=0;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    if(!hole[i][j]&&!temp[i][j])
                        count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
    static void pathtoexit(int r,int c)
    {
        if(temp[r][c]||hole[r][c])
            return;
        if(r-1>=0)
            pathtoexit(r-1,c);
        if(c-1>=0)
            pathtoexit(r,c-1);
        temp[r][c]=true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, this fails when the size of the grid NxM is very large, of the order of 10^5 or more. I get an error of "Java heap overflow".

Can anyone please help me sort this issue out and make the necessary changes in the code as required ?

Comment: You probably don't have to create two arrays one for `hole` and one for `temp`

Comment: You don't have enough run time or memory to create the maze and iterate through it.  You'll have to solve this problem with mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to propose changes to your code because your approach to the problem is not really practical. You are using a brute force approach to find every path but the problem's parameters allow for a 10^6 x 10^6 maze - finding a path from every cell is really not practical as it could require you to check 10^18 cells which would take more time than the current age of the universe!

The solution here is to start with the insight that the only way for a cell to be 'BAD' is if it is caught behind intersecting horizontal and vertical lines of holes (considering the edges to also represent holes). The secret is to look for those groups and calculate how many 'BAD' cells they generate.

Comment: Thanks I will try coming up with some different approach to this problem.

Comment: Your algorithm is a kind of very brutal. You don't have to build the "maze"... You have to find the property that leads to conclude BAD...